# Polar form vs phasor form?

Tags: phasor

I know that polar form has two parts. Amplitude and angle but
What is difference between polar form and phasor form of complex numbers?  Or phasor form just includes amplitude form of a complex number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A phasor is a complex representation of the magnitude and phase of a sinusoid and is based on Euler's identity:

$$ e^{\pm j\phi} = cos(\phi) \pm j sin(\phi) $$

If you have a sinusoidal voltage given by: $$ v(t) = V_m cos(\omega t + \phi)$$
you can express it in phasor form by first taking the real part of it

$$v(t) = Re(V_me^{j(\omega t + \phi)})$$
thus 
$$v(t) = Re(V e^{j\omega t})$$
where
$$V = V_m e^{j\phi} = V_m \angle \phi$$

V is thus a phasor representation of the sinusiod v(t)

So having show that you can see that a **phasor** is a complex number in a polar form.

Comment: Your phasor form appears to be more or less same as polar form

Comment: Yes I have updated my answer to address your main concern - phasor and polar form difference.

Comment: You need to explain how \$Re(V_m e^{j(\omega t+\phi)})=Re(Ve^{j\omega t}\$), and also why \$t\$ has disappeared in the final equation; \$\omega\$ is not an angle.

Comment: There was a typo in my first post which I now corrected. Anyway, if you write $$e^{j(\omega t + \phi)})$$ as a product of two e and then in equation 3 substitute $$V = V_m e^{j \phi}$$ you will get what I wrote in equation 4. As for why t was dropped - well this is the essence of phasor representation, we are not interested in time related informations.

Comment: The term phasor is just to distinguish from space vector.